# Yeoman custom generator

Tags: yeoman

I would like to make a custom generator with the latest version of yeoman, but I'm having some difficulty. I've been digging around various sources of documentation and examples (like the webapp and angular generators), but I still have a few questions.

1. What is the workflow for testing a generator? If I have one project that is the generator itself, do I keep making new directories to run `yo my-generator`?
2. Has the generator framework changed at all with the beta of `yo` 1.0? Have there been breaking changes?
3. How does a generator register itself with the global `yo` binary?

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> What is the workflow for testing a generator?

I'll be working on this in the next couple of days for generator-angular. You can [track my progress on Github](https://github.com/yeoman/generator-angular/issues/5). Unfortunately, there aren't too many examples yet because of the transition from one `yeoman` command to using `yo` alongside `bower` and `yo`. I imagine there will be some level of unit testing on the `Generator.prototype.method`, as well as E2E testing that involves writing bash scripts to run `yo`, `npm`, `bower`, and `grunt`.

> Has the generator framework changed at all with the beta of yo 1.0? Have there been breaking changes?

In my experience porting over generator-angular, I haven't seen too many changes. There is a new, optional [simplified API](https://github.com/yeoman/generator/issues/152), which may be useful.

> How does a generator register itself with the global `yo` binary?

The answer right now is that it doesn't. You install/use generators in a project directory. I somehow had it working due to an errant symlink, but that's not the recommended way of doing it.

Answer (score 7):

This question is a few months old, but I think it's useful for anyone who finds it now to know that much more has been explained in http://yeoman.io/generators.html

Question 1:

Testing your generators locally can be easily done. For instance if your generator is called "generator-mtv-raps"

```
$ cd ~/dev/generator-mtv-raps/
$ npm link
```

Now if you do:

```
$ cd ~/dev/mytest/
$ yo mtv-raps
```

It will build.

Additionally, unit testing your generator with mocha is pretty straight forward. There is a set of test helpers built in. The basics of what you need to be testing against can be found  in generator-webapp's tests https://github.com/yeoman/generator-webapp/blob/master/test/test.js

1. Test that the generator can be required without breaking.
2. Mock your prompts with `helpers.mockPrompt`
3. Test that all the files you want created are created via `helpers.assertFiles`
4. Test that the prompt values you mocked are inserted into the created files.

Number 4 is kind of tricky, the array of expected files can be passed a regular expression to check against. If you want to know more about the test helpers, the source is the best place. https://github.com/yeoman/generator/blob/master/lib/test/helpers.js

Question 2: already answered by btford

Question 3:

Generators are bound to `yo` by installing them globally (or linking them as above) and using a naming convention. All generators start with "generator" then "-" then "name".

hence `generator-mtv-raps` accessed via `$ yo mtv-raps`